# How to read a multiple values in cell in each row (separated by comma) in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have problem in reading cell with multiple values and comparing the each value with column from a-z if match found then set value of the cell has '1'.

Problem: I need to take multiple company names in the list and take one company and look for the same in the columns if match is found then set the value as `1` and read each consecutive columns.

Please find a sample spreadsheet: [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Anb14r4oI7KOdHNaLVh6cklHQ09XdF8yRHdmdmZsb2c&output=html). Currently I'm learning Google scripting so I need your help.

Comment: please [edit] & mention what's the "problem" you're facing and what have you tried

Comment: Can you share a Google Spreadsheet with us and show the expected result? Try editing your question and add the Google Spreadsheets tag also to it. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your feed backs to both of you.....now i have linked the spreadsheet u can have look and suggestion how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed the last two rows are incomplete rather than a guide to your requirement, so would suggest:

```
=if(iserror(find(C$1,$B2)),"",1)
```

in the column labelled `aaa` and the row labelled `abc`, copied across and down to suit.